# How to pass CSV Datasource to subReport

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I need your help in  passing csv datasource to subReports .

I would highly appreciate your suggestion  or solutions.

I am using *iReport 5.0  professional version*.
I have a very complex report and that report fetch data from multiple (approx 10) csv files.

I have created subReports for each section of the reports and each subReport is working fine as a indivisual Report.

But when i try to integrate all the subReports into a main Reports , then i am not able to pass datasource to the subReports.

In Main report, i created a  parameter  called CSVDS  of type *net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRCsvDataSource* with its default value as following:
`new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRCsvDataSource(new File("D:\\client\\data\\SR1.csv"))`
and in order to make sure that CSVDS is getting value from SR1.CVS , i added a textbod with following expression and it returned true

$P{CVSDS}.next() -- return true --which means that CSVDS gets populated from the data from SR1.csv

Further, i passed $P{CVSDS} as datasource to the subReport

```
<subreport>

<reportElement uuid="2f0d77ac-ce39-4487-8f31-0e15e03f5dfd" x="0" y="0" width="592" height="437"/>

<dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$P{CSVDS}]]></dataSourceExpression>

<subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "P1.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>

</subreport>
```

but the subReports was coming blank.

So, overall, i would like to know how can i pass csv datasource to subReports .

PS : I have tried almost all the solutions available on Stack overflow and Jasper community site but nothing worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the datasource expression to the proper type:

```
<subreport>

<reportElement uuid="2f0d77ac-ce39-4487-8f31-0e15e03f5dfd" x="0" y="0" width="592" height="437"/>

<dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[(net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRCsvDataSource)$P{CSVDS}]]></dataSourceExpression>

<subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "P1.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>

</subreport>
```